# Subtracting ruby variables which are the count of an active record object association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables, math, operators

I have an app for authors and book reviewers. Recently I have wrapped up a feature where a moderator can vote reviews as helpful or not helpful, which determines the reviewer's score (to keep their reviews in check). I have a review model with helpful and not_helpful as boolean columns on the table set to false by default. When the moderator clicks the link on the review show if it was helpful or not helpful that then updates the boolean value to true for that review record. I am trying to build a score card on that reviewer's profile where I use math to subtract the non_helpful reviews from the total review count for a user, and then divide that sum by the total review count to arrive at a percentage for that reviewer's score. Essentially when their reviews aren't helpful that's a mark against them and it's like getting a question wrong on a test. So out of all the reviews, we want to subtract all the nonhelpful reviews from the total reviews and take that answer and divide it by the total reviews to get their score. So far I have this:

users_controller.rb

```
def profile
    @current_user = current_user
    @helpful = current_user.reviews.where(helpful: true)
    @unhelpful = current_user.reviews.where(unhelpful: true)
    @reviews = current_user.reviews
    unhelpful = @unhelpful.count
    total = @reviews.count
    subtotal = total - unhelpful
    @score = subtotal / total  

  end
```

profile.html.erb

## Welcome Reviewer,

```
<h2>How I'm doing</h3>

<table>
  <th>Total Reviews</th>
  <th>Helpful Reviews</th>
  <th>Unhelpful Reviews</th>
  <th>Score</th>
  <tr>
    <td><%= current_user.reviews.count %></td>
    <td><%= @helpful.count %></td>
    <td><%= @unhelpful.count %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_percentage(@score * 100, precision: 0) 
%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I haven't ever done simpe ruby math with operators and setting variables to active record objects and calling count on them before, so what is the right way of doing that? Right now the user score is 0% which isn't right lol because the current reviewer I'm logged in as has 4 total reviews, 2 helpful and 2 unhelpful which should give them a score of 50% according to the scoring system I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called "integer division". When both operands are integers, the result will be too. So either make one/both operands float

```
@score = subtotal.to_f / total
```

or use `fdiv`

```
@score = subtotal.fdiv(total)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer. And that makes sense. Since you answered so quick I have to wait 8 minutes according to stackoverflow before I can even mark your asnwer as the answer to my question haha

Comment: @dmberko11: I should have marked this question as a duplicate, though, but I'm too tired to look for good dup target.

Comment: Yeah, I tried lo look at similar questions first before remaking this tired question since it's been asking in a bunch of other ways. I figured it had to do with my numbers from my variables being integers since that's what they are when you query the count of a record. And in order to do division they need to be floats. Makes sense now